# CBC-MAC insecure with random IV

Tags: mac, cbc, cbc-mac

4. Prove that the following modification of $\operatorname{CBC-MAC}$ does not yield a secure fixed-length $\operatorname{MAC}$:

   Modify $\operatorname{CBC-MAC}$ so that a random $IV$ is used each time a tag is computed (and the $IV$ is output along with $t_l$). I.e., $t_0 \leftarrow \{0, 1\}^n$ is chosen uniformly at random rather than being fixed to $0^n$, and the tag is $t_0, t_l$.

   **Answer.** The scheme is not secure. In particular, let $m$ be a one-block message and let $(IV, t)$ be its $\operatorname{MAC}$-tag received from the oracle. Then, the tag $(m, t)$ is a valid $\operatorname{MAC}$ for the message $IV$. (More generally, for any $m'$ the tag $(IV \oplus m', t)$ is a valid $\operatorname{MAC}$ for the message $m \oplus m'$. This means that it is possible to generate a forgery for any desired single-block message.)

From the paper [CIS 5371 Cryptography, Home Assignment 4](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~burmeste/cis5371/quiz/HA4-sol.pdf)

My question is how is the tag $(m,t)$ a valid forgery. This is my understanding:
[image: my understanding]
If I used numbers so $m=101, IV=110, m\oplus IV=011$, but the forgery says that I can use m, so that $m=101, IV=101, m\oplus IV=000$, which is obviously not the case. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Then, the tag (m,t) is a valid MAC **for the message IV***.

In other words, given a tag $(IV,t)$ for a message $m$, you can construct a tag $(m,t)$ for the message $IV$. So your understanding is wrong. It is not $m\oplus m$ in the forgery, it is $IV\oplus m$ which is the same as $m\oplus IV$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m_1 = 0^n, IV_1 = 011$ then, \begin{align}&F_k(m_1 \oplus IV_1)\\ =& F_k(0^n \oplus 011)\\ =& F_k(011).\end{align} Now, we can construct a different message $m_2 = 010$ and a valid tag for it in the following way: choose $IV_2 = 001$ and output \begin{align}&\langle m_2, IV_2, t_2\rangle\\ =&\langle010, 001,F_k(010 \oplus 001)\rangle\\ = &\langle010, 001,F_k(011)\rangle.\end{align}
It's clear that for $m_1 \ne m_2$ we have produced a valid tag for $m_2$. We didn't need to know $F_k$.